# Drawing a sphere with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Can someone please tell me which part of the code I'm messing up?

In glDrawElements, I got like only [1/3 of the sphere with "indices.size() / 3"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHcJV.png) , which was how most tutorial was conducted, but when I tried `indices.size()`, I got segmentation fault and nothing showed up.

```
vector<GLfloat> vertices, normals, texCoords;
vector<GLushort> indices;

void setupSphere(double r, int slice, int stack)
{
    vertices.resize(slice * stack * 3);
    normals.resize(slice * stack * 3);
    texCoords.resize(slice * stack * 2);

    float x, y, z, xz;
    float nx, ny, nz, lengthInv = 1.0f / r;
    float s, t;

    float sliceAngle, stackAngle;

    vector<GLfloat>::iterator itV = vertices.begin();
    vector<GLfloat>::iterator itN = normals.begin();
    vector<GLfloat>::iterator itT = texCoords.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < stack; i++)
    {
        stackAngle = M_PI_2 - M_PI * i / stack;
        xz = r * cosf(stackAngle);
        y = r * sinf(stackAngle);

        for (int j = 0; j < slice; j++)
        {
            sliceAngle = 2 * M_PI * j / slice;

            x = xz * sinf(sliceAngle);
            z = xz * cosf(sliceAngle);
            *itV++ = x;
            *itV++ = y;
            *itV++ = z;

            nx = x * lengthInv;
            ny = y * lengthInv;
            nz = z * lengthInv;
            *itN++ = nx;
            *itN++ = ny;
            *itN++ = nz;

            s = (float)j / slice;
            t = (float)i / stack;
            *itT++ = s;
            *itT++ = t;
        }
    }

    int first, second;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < slice; j++)
        {
            first = i * slice + j;
            second = first + slice + 1;

            indices.push_back(first);
            indices.push_back(second);
            indices.push_back(first + 1);

            indices.push_back(first + 1);
            indices.push_back(second);
            indices.push_back(second + 1);
        }
    }
}

void drawSphere()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &normals[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &texCoords[0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indices[0]);
}
```

Comment: Your sphere looks too smooth. How many vertices do you have?

Comment: I’m going with 360 for longitude and 180 for latitude, but the number of vertices seemed to have little influence on the smoothness of the sphere, which I don’t understand why.

Comment: Then you have 194400 vertices, way more than what can be indexed by `GLushort`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The correct is indeed `indices.size() / 3`, because you must pass the number of triangles, not the number of indices.</s>

The correct is indeed `indices.size()`, because you must pass the number of elements in the array you are passing. I don't know why the tutorials you saw used `/ 3` variation.

As to the problem of the missing sphere section, my best guess with the provided information is that you have more than 65535 vertices, so the indices wraps around that value, because you are using `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

Try changing from `vector<GLushort> indices;` to `vector<GLuint> indices;` and using `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` in `glDrawElements()`.

Alternatively, lower the values of `slice` and `stack` so that `slice * stack * 3 <= 65535`.

Comment: Oh, that was right! Sorry for forgetting those int vs short things. But indices.size() / 3 still only draws 1/3 of the sphere, whereas indices.size() gives a full one, any idea?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong interpreting the [documentation for `glDrawElements()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml). I interpreted "elements" as "primitives", but maybe it really means "indices", and then the correct is `indices.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

You generate *N* stacks and *M* slices. Hence you can just create *(N-1)x(M-1)* quads.
The indices of the quads are *(first, first+slice, first+1, first+slice+1)*, where *first* is the first index of the quad:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < stack-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < slice-1; j++)
    {
        int first = i*slice + j;
        unsigned short qi[]{first, first+slice, first+1, first+slice+1};

        indices.insert(indices.end(), {qi[0], qi[2], qi[3], qi[0], qi[3], qi[1]});
    }
}
```

---

See the answer to the questions [Sphere Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080505/sphere-calculations/49081855#49081855) and [How to map texture to sphere that rendered by parametric equation using points primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380127/how-to-map-texture-to-sphere-that-rendered-by-parametric-equation-using-points-p/48388897#48388897).

Comment: `*itV++ = x;` is indeed the same as `*itV = x; itV++`, except for sequence points, which is not an issue here unless the operators= and * are overloaded and have side effects.

Comment: @lvella You're right. Side note, the _count_ argument of [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) specifies the number of indices, not the number of [primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive).